# How can i get image from this site?

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests

I have error on 7th line.
I have troubles only with this hosting(https://prnt.sc/), i got the next error:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)

I tried to use other libraries, like urllib and wget, had the same trouble

```
import requests
from random import choice
alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
url_start = 'm3sm4x'
url_finish = 'https://prnt.sc/'+url_start+'.img'
filename = 'D:\\imgur\\content\\'+url_finish.split('/')[-1]
img = requests.get(url_finish, stream=True)
n = 0
while n != 100:
    url_start = url_start.replace(choice(url_start),choice(alph))
    url_finish = 'https://prnt.sc/'+url_start+'.img'
    n+=1
    try:
        img = requests.get(url_finish, stream=True)
    except:
        print('invalid')
    if img.status_code == 200:
        with open('D:\\imgur\\content\\'+filename,' wb') as f:
            f.write(img)
```

Comment: I get an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'choice'` error on the line `url_start = url_start.replace(url_start.choice,alph.choice)` so it's unclear what you're attempting to do.

Comment: anyway, i got error before

Comment: i fixed this, `choice` take random element from sequence

Comment: OK, that makes a little more sense...except for you seeming to expect you can get a valid image name from somewhat randomly scrambling the url for one. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Can you write a simpler version of the code?  One that has a static URL instead of one that is all built-up?

Comment: yes, i can get a valid image, it is an idea of this program.
Anyway, 1st link is valid 100%

Comment: i have an error in this line:
`img = requests.get('https://prnt.sc/m3sm4x', stream=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to download image using [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/):

```
import os.path
import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://prnt.sc/m3sm4x')
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
for image in images:
    img_url = image.get_attribute('src')
    file_name = os.path.basename(img_url)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, file_name)
    except:
        pass
driver.close()
```

Comment: sorry, i never use  selenium before, and this code opens this link in browser, nothing more

Comment: Yes, and then downloads all images from that link

Comment: In which path ?

Comment: urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, file_name)

Comment: ty, it works!
1 more question, can u explain why had i get my error?

Comment: Trty to remove `stream=True` from `img = requests.get('https://prnt.sc/m3sm4x', stream=True)`

Comment: i already tried this, one guy said me, that this hosting is rly bad, cause return 520 error

Answer (score 0):

I decided my problem by python reinstalling.